# JQuery - Modal dialog seems to be disabling its form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery Modal Dialog disables form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819213/jquery-modal-dialog-disables-form-elements)

I'm using JQuery UI to make a modal dialog, I have the html code in my page set to display:none and the modal is shown on button click, the modal shows fine but all the text fields that I have in it are locked, for some reason. Anyone had this issue?

EDIT:

Here's the code of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/5Xmmb/1/ here it seems to work. What I meant by locked is that my fields seem to be disabled in my actual code.

Comment: Sounds like the modal dialog box is disabling all form elements instead of just form elements on the page. When you display a Modal you are supposed to interact with it before you can go back to interacting with the page.

What do you mean that the text fields are 'locked' ? Are they hidden or read only?

Comment: Mind showing some HTML and javascript? I've use modal with forms before and haven't had that problem, leading me to believe there's something in your code.

Comment: what do you mean by locked? And can you provide a demo or at least some code?

Comment: you need to use a Modal Form instead of a Modal Dialog. Check out my answer below.

Comment: @ImportedNoob yes, I am supposed to interact with it before resuming my other tasks, or just close it if the user wishes

Comment: Did you forget "open" inside of `.dialog( "open" )` when you went to display your Modal form?

Comment: No, it's there in my code, the dialog does prompt me, it's just the form fields that are disabled

Answer (score 1):

The z-index of the form is most likely the problem.  Try setting it to "auto":

```
#my_dialog_form {
    z-index: auto;
}
```